# Momentum 0.9 and 0.99 in SGD

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, deep-learning, caffe

I have a SGD solver:

```
base_lr: 1e-2    
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1       
stepsize: 10000  
max_iter: 300000  
momentum: 0.9
```

As suggestion in the Caffe's documentation, they said that "if you increase μ, it may be a good idea to decrease α accordingly (and vice versa)". Hence, if I choose momentum is `0.99`, then I believe that the `base_lr` must be `1e-4`

```
base_lr: 1e-4    
lr_policy: "step"
gamma: 0.1       
stepsize: 10000  
max_iter: 300000  
momentum: 0.99
```

Am I right?  Do I need to increase the `stepsize` too?  What is benefit using a bigger momentum (i.e `0.99`), compared to a smaller momentum (i.e `0.9`)?

Comment: The solver is highly dependent on the model topology.  You're asking for advice on tuning an unknown model.  This leaves your questions too general to answer accurately.

Comment: Also, please ask in terms of the interactions.  Do you know what these hyper-parameters (momentum, learning rate, and stepsize) do for the training?  If not, please change your question to ask what *you* need to know.  [on topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) would apply here.

Comment: Please finish the sentence fragment that ends with "then my solver will be".

Comment: Yes i know it. My question just focus on does it same for case of monentum 0.9 learning rate 0.001 and momentum 0.99 learning rate 0.0001  for any networks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for the clarification.  No, this is not a direct correlation.  The amount of change you need is something you determine by experimentation for your data set and max_iter (which also needs tuning).  You might find that the best `lr` for momentum 0.99 is 1e-3, 1e-5, or something else.  You might find that 0.99 is too heavy for best results, and you need to back off to 0.92 or 0.97

Without proper details on the situation, I can't guess at what will work for you better than the guess ranges I just gave.  My work has focused more on tuning the other hyper-parameters; momentum = 0.90 served us well for all of our applications.

Comment: Thanks for answer. In my case, learning rate and momentum are highly depends on the performance. The momentum 0.99 gives the loss more stabler

Comment: That makes the loss quite stable.  What is "performance" for you?  Accuracy of the trained model?  Time to train to a minimum accuracy?

Comment: It is loss per iterations metric

Comment: I'm unclear how loss divided by iteration number gives a useful quantity.  This should tend to decrease throughout training, with an asymptote of 0 as time grows larger.